# difference between object reference of Integer class in java

Tags: java, integer, equals, operator-keyword, object-reference

I have doubt in Following code object references in java.
here is the code.

```
    public class Simple{
public static void main(String args[]){
 Integer a=150,b=150;
        System.out.println(a==b);

        Integer c=100,d=100;
        System.out.println(c==d);
}}
```

I can compile and execute the above code in online compiler and I got answers 
***false true***.And my doubt is Why i can't get second one is false? it's also object reference isn't it?. Please someone can help me to clear the doubt.Thanks in advance

Comment: However, I have tried this in the online java compiler [(tutorialspoint)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php)  and I've got the same output. This could not be happened on the Java run-time. This is an issue with the site itself.

Comment: @user7328702 tutorialspoint may not be the most trustworthy resource to use.

Comment: If we assign values to integer objects while converting them java use `valueOf()`. The representation of value of method cache the values for better performance. See the documentation of valueOf() method.

Comment: I have tried this without using an online compiler. I am getting the same result as you. The reason is Integer is an object. It unwraps the value as an int when you assign smaller numbers. see >> [Java Integer Comparison](https://senuradissanayake.wordpress.com/2018/04/10/java-integer-comparisons/)